# Least squares method common factor

Tags: derivatives, least-squares

For the least squares method why is a factor of 2 taken out when removing the square of the residual? It's probably glaringly obvious but I can't see it.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
R &=& \sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y}_i-y_i)^2\\
 &=& \sum_{i=1}^nr_i^2\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial R}{\partial x_j} &=& 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_i\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial x_j}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Just for convenience, as the expression will be identified to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the chain rule, i.e., $f(g(x))$, then 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) g'(x),
$$
thus $g(x) = x\beta - y$ and $f(x) = x^2$, hence 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(g(x)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} ( x\beta - y) ^2 = f'(g(x)) g'(x) = 2( x\beta -y)x.
$$